# Custom Scheme indexing function returns list-external value

Tags: indexing, lambda, linked-list, scheme, guile

I'm a newbie to scheme programming and I was writing small codes when I encountered the following issue and couldn't reason about it satisfactorily.

```
(define (at_i lst i)
  (if (eq? i 0)
    (car lst)
    (at_i (cdr lst)
          (- i  1) )))
```

Evaluation of `(at_i '(1 2 3 4) 0)` returns `1`.
Now lets define same procedure with a lambda syntax.

```
(define (at_i lst i)
  (lambda (vec x)
    (if (eq? x 0)
      (car vec)
      (at_i (cdr vec)
            (- x  1) )))
  lst i)
```

But now Evaluation of `(at_i '(1 2 3 4) 0)` returns `0`, which is not in the list and in general, it returns element at index-1.

I don't understand why this is happening.

Note: I just realized its not returning element at index - 1 but the index itself. The reason for this has been well explained below by @Renzo. Thanks!

Comment: Standard naming convention in Scheme is `at-i`.

Comment: Just in case: Scheme's linked list is a fundamentally different data structure than, for example, C++'s dynamic-array based `vec`tor.

Answer (score 3):

First, you should indent properly the code if you intend to learn the language, since code indentation is very important to understand programs in Scheme and Lisp-like languages.

For instance, your function correctly indented is:

```
(define (at_i lst i)
  (lambda (vec x)
    (if (eq? x 0)
        (car vec)
        (at_i (cdr vec) (- x  1))))
  lst
  i)
```

From this you can see that you are defining the function `at_i` exactly as before in terms of a function with two parameters (`lst` and `i`), and whose body is constitued by three expressions: the first `lambda (vec x) ... (- x 1))))`, which is an (anonymous) function (`lambda`) which is not called or applied, the second, which is the first parameter `lst`, and finally the third which is the second parameter `i`. So, when the function `at_i` is called with two arguments, the result is the evaluation of the three expressions in sequence, the first two values are discarded (the function and the value of `lst`), and the result is the value of the second parameter `i`. This is reason for which the result of `(at_i '(1 2 3 4) 0)` is `0`, since it is the value of `i`.

A proper redefinition of the function in lambda form would be the following, for instance:

```
(define at_i
  (lambda (vec x)
    (if (eq? x 0)
        (car vec)
        (at_i (cdr vec) (- x  1)))))

(at_i '(1 2 3 4) 0)  ;; => 1
```

in which you can see that the name `at_i`, through the `define`, is associated to a two parameter function which calculates correctly the result.

Answer (score 1):

`eq?` is memory object equality. Only some Scheme implementations interpret `(eq? 5 5)` as `#t`. Use `=` for numbers, `eqv?` for values, and `equal?` for collections.

```
(define (index i xs)       ; `index` is a partial function,
   (if (= i 0)             ; `i` may go out of range
      (car xs)
      (index (- i 1)       ; Tail recursion
             (cdr xs) )))
```

Your second function returns the index because you missed parenthesis around the lambda's application. It should be

```
(define (index i xs)
   ((lambda (i' xs')
       (if (= i' 0)
          (car xs')
          (index (- i' 1)      ; Not tail-recursive
                 (cdr xs') )))
    i xs))
```

But this is verbose and differs semantically from the first formulation.

Answer (score -1):

You say you are defining the "same procedure with a lambda syntax", but you are not. That would be `(define at_i (lambda lst i) ...)`. Instead, you are effectively saying `(define (at_i lst i) 1 2 3)`, and that is `3`, of course.

In your particular case, you defined the procedure `at_i` to return `(lambda (vec x) ...)`, `lst` and `i`. Now, if you call `(at_i '(1 2 3 4) 0)`, the procedure will return `0`, since that is the value of `i` at this point.

Comment: So where is 0 coming from? maybe you should explain it a little bit more as I'm noob to this paradigm of programming.